# python3.PyImport_ImportModule(name) will emit a fatal error when called the second time

Tags: python-3.x, go

**Environments**:

- MacOS (Catalina Version 10.15.4)
- Python3.7.6
- Go1.13.8

I want to use go-python3 to invoke an algorithm written in Python3, but as described, a fatal error will generated when the second time I invoke this algorithm. From the output message, it seems that `PyImport_ImportModule` causes this error.

```
fatal error: unexpected signal during runtime execution
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0xa pc=0x91256a3]

runtime stack:
runtime.throw(0x4967a75, 0x2a)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:774 +0x72
runtime.sigpanic()
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/signal_unix.go:378 +0x47c

goroutine 41 [syscall]:
runtime.cgocall(0x4637740, 0xc000063c18, 0x48a4660)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/cgocall.go:128 +0x5b fp=0xc000063be8 sp=0xc000063bb0 pc=0x4004d0b
github.com/DataDog/go-python3._Cfunc_PyImport_ImportModule(0x8061d90, 0x0)
        _cgo_gotypes.go:3780 +0x4a fp=0xc000063c18 sp=0xc000063be8 pc=0x462c2fa
github.com/DataDog/go-python3.PyImport_ImportModule(0x49501f5, 0x8, 0x0)
        /Users/zhao/go/pkg/mod/github.com/!data!dog/go-python3@v0.0.0-20191126174558-6ed25e33b3c4/import.go:24 +0x87 fp=0xc000063c80 sp=0xc000063c18 pc=0x462e267
PPGServer/pkg/algo.ImportModule(0x4964926, 0x26, 0x49501f5, 0x8, 0x1)
        /Users/zhao/go/src/PPGServer/pkg/algo/ppg.go:42 +0x4cb fp=0xc000063d98 sp=0xc000063c80 pc=0x46332db
PPGServer/pkg/algo.CalcPre(0xc0003560c0, 0xd, 0x0, 0x0)
....
```

Here is the sample code.
**A wrapper of PyImport_ImportModule**:

```
// ImportModule will import python module from given directory
func ImportModule(dir, name string) *python3.PyObject {
    fmt.Println("python3.PyImport_ImportModule before")
    sysModule := python3.PyImport_ImportModule("sys") // import sys
    fmt.Println("python3.PyImport_ImportModule success")
    path := sysModule.GetAttrString("path")           // path = sys.path
    ob := python3.PyList_GetItem(path, 1)
    fmt.Println("check:", python3.PyUnicode_Check(ob))
    fmt.Println("path:", python3.PyUnicode_AsUTF8(ob))
    fmt.Println("sysModule.GetAttrString success")
    python3.PyList_Insert(path, 0, python3.PyUnicode_FromString("/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages"))
    python3.PyList_Insert(path, 0, python3.PyUnicode_FromString(dir))
    fmt.Println("After module insert:", python3.PyUnicode_AsUTF8(python3.PyList_GetItem(path, 0)))
    fmt.Println("module name:", name)
    return python3.PyImport_ImportModule(name) 
}
```

Each time the algorithm is called in a goroutine.

```
func CalcPre(dataFilePath string) (sbpI int, dbpI int) {
    python3.Py_Initialize()
    if !python3.Py_IsInitialized() {
        fmt.Println("Error initializing the python interpreter")
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    gstate = python3.PyGILState_Ensure()
    fmt.Println("Py_Initialize success")
    vbp := ImportModule("/Users/zhao/Desktop/lab/ppython", "value_bp")
    fmt.Println("ImportModule success")

    b := vbp.GetAttrString("estimate")
    fmt.Printf("[FUNC] b = %#v\n", b)
    bArgs := python3.PyTuple_New(1)
    python3.PyTuple_SetItem(bArgs, 0, python3.PyUnicode_FromString(dataFilePath))
    re := b.Call(bArgs, python3.Py_None)
    sbp := python3.PyTuple_GetItem(re, 0)
    dbp := python3.PyTuple_GetItem(re, 1)
    defer func() {
        python3.Py_Finalize()
        fmt.Println("python3.Py_Finalize()")
    }()
    sbpI = python3.PyLong_AsLong(sbp)
    dbpI = python3.PyLong_AsLong(dbp)
    python3.PyGILState_Release(gstate)
    return
}

func Calc(dataFilePath string) {
    CalcPre(dataFilePath)
}
```

Sample caller  like this: `go Calc("aaa.csv")`.

To reproduce this, use the code above and environments above, put these code into a goroutine, like `go Calc("aaa.csv")`.For simplicity, you may just remove the algorithm part and just have the skeleton remained.

To be simple, you can use this code as well to reproduce this issue:

```
func CalcPre(dataFilePath string) (sbpI int, dbpI int) {
    python3.Py_Initialize()
    if !python3.Py_IsInitialized() {
        fmt.Println("Error initializing the python interpreter")
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    gstate = python3.PyGILState_Ensure()
    ImportModule("/Users/zhao/Desktop/lab/ppython", "value_bp")
    defer func() {
        python3.Py_Finalize()
        fmt.Println("python3.Py_Finalize()")
    }()
    
    return
}
```

Comment: To be more specific, in ```python3.PyImport_ImportModule(name)```, if the ```name``` is a self defined module like ```value_bp```, it will cause this issue when called the second time. But it will be OK if the ```name``` is official module like ```sys```,```time```.

Answer (score -2):

Here is an option to achieve the same purpose.
**Just use `os/exec` package**~~~

1. Use `exec.Command` to set executable binary and its arguments,
   sample code:
   `cmd := exec.Command("python3", "test.py", "./srcdata/aaa.csv")`
2. Use `cmd.Dir` to set the command working directory;
3. Use `output := cmd.CombinedOutput()` to run this command and get its stdout information;
4. Do whatever you want to deal with the `output`.

Full snippet as follows:

```
func Calc(dataFilePath string) (sI int, dI int) {
    cmd := exec.Command("python3", "test.py", "./srcdata/"+dataFilePath)
    cmd.Dir = "/Users/username/Desktop/lab/ppython"
    output, e := cmd.CombinedOutput()
    if e != nil {
        fmt.Println("Python Execution Error :", e)
    }
    result := string(output)
    strs := strings.Split(result, "\n")
    sI, e = strconv.Atoi(strs[0])
    dI, e = strconv.Atoi(strs[1])
    return
}
```

Anyway, this could handle most inter-language operations for me.